# Can Swagger Code Gen SDKs handle OAuth token refresh?

Tags: oauth, sdk, oauth-2.0, swagger, auto-generate

Can SDKs created by Swagger Code Gen (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) manage OAuth token refresh by storing and using a refresh token to automatically refresh an expired access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, clients generated bySwagger-Codegen do not support automatic refresh of token in any way.

You can submit a feature request [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues) to see if the community has cycle to add the feature. Remember to provide details of your requirement and a sample spec if you've one.

Comment: We have got the same requirement recently. Does swagger-codegen newer versions support this?